# SQL Query To Obtain Values that contains multiple instances within a time range

Tags: mysql

I want to only find accounts that have more than one instance of a closed_date within their own 30 day, 3 month, and 1 year period which ends at their own monthly, quarterly, and annual expiration date. However each account has its own expiration date range.
My WHERE clause is where I can’t seem to figure out how to implement the proper 30 day, quarterly, and yearly range.

I'm not sure if the BETWEEN clause is appropriate or if I should be using a greater than / less than.

```
SELECT a.acct, COUNT(d.closed_date) AS cd, a.billing_expiration_date
FROM docupaid d
INNER JOIN account a ON a.acct=d.acct
WHERE (d.closed_date) BETWEEN (a.bill_expiration_date minus 30 days) AND a.billing_expiration_date                    
GROUP BY acct desc
HAVING cd>1
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: In Postgres (and Oracle) you could simply write `a.bill_expiration_date - 30`

Comment: Look at `datediff` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [DATE_SUB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) function:

```
SELECT a.acct, 
       COUNT(d.closed_date) AS cd, 
       a.billing_expiration_date
FROM docupaid d
INNER JOIN account a ON a.acct=d.acct
WHERE d.closed_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(a.bill_expiration_date, INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
                            AND a.billing_expiration_date                    
GROUP BY acct desc
HAVING cd > 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Is there a way to include a 3 month and 1 year interval within that same WHERE clause?

Comment: @JDoc do consider upvoting the answer as well. Thanks :)